# JS errors crash JUCE app

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, juce

Developing a React Native app that is based on JUCE, using an iOS device for testing, whenever there is a JS error in my code the app crashes and I have to restart from Xcode. The `Reload` button does not work.

The core of the app is a JUCE application. In Debug mode I get the following exception on JS errors:

```
exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[JuceAppStartupDelegate window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I understand that this is because `JuceAppStartupDelegate` does not have a `window` property. What I don't know is how to implement a `JUCEApplication` instance that would respond to the call made by React Native.

Comment: What error(s), specifically, are you getting?

Comment: It could be any JS error - updated the question with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out a solution.

The React Native code that was causing the crash was in the `dismiss` method:

```
- (void)dismiss
{
  self.hidden = YES;
  [self resignFirstResponder];
  [RCTSharedApplication().delegate.window makeKeyWindow]; // <-- crash here
}
```

I tried simply commenting the offending line out. And it works - I can now use the Reload button after JS errors in my React Native code.

```
- (void)dismiss
{
  self.hidden = YES;
  [self resignFirstResponder];
  //[RCTSharedApplication().delegate.window makeKeyWindow];
}
```

**EDIT (Jan 2017)**:

JUCE has since been updated with a `window` property on iOS, which resolves this error.